# Print backwards in c++

Tags: c++

Here is a program where I enter a sentence and print it backward...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string scrambleWords;
    cout << "Please enter a sentence to scramble: ";
    getline(cin, scrambleWords);

    for (int print = scrambleWords.length() - 1; print >= 0; print--)
    {
        if (isspace(scrambleWords[print]))
        {
            for (unsigned int printIt = print + 1; 
                         printIt < scrambleWords.length(); printIt++)
            {
                cout << scrambleWords[printIt];
                if (isspace(scrambleWords[printIt]))
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int gotIt = 0; gotIt < scrambleWords.length(); gotIt++)
    {
        cout << scrambleWords[gotIt];
        if (isspace(scrambleWords[gotIt]))
            break;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// OUTPUT
// Please enter a sentence: birds and bees
// beesand birds
// Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see there was no space between bees & birds, so how can I add the space in there?

Comment: You print each word and the space that follows. There is no space after bees, so none is printed.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest and easiest solution is to rely on the standard libraray:

```
// 1. Get your input string like you did

// 2. Save the sentence as vector of words:
stringstream sentence {scrambleWords};
vector<string> words;
copy(istream_iterator<string>{sentence},istream_iterator<string>{},
    back_inserter(words));

// 3 a) Output the vector in reverse order
for (auto i = words.rbegin(); i != words.rend(); ++i)
    cout << *i << " ";

// 3 b) or reverse the vector, then print it
reverse(words.begin(),words.end());
for (const auto& x : words)
    cout << x << " ";
```

Comment: @user2957078 Learning the standard library is good advice in general. It is saver (harder to get wrong), probably faster (smart people worked hard to optimize it) and easily readable and maintainable for every decent C++ programmer. And of course, you save precious time on developing and debugging your handmade solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like (C++11 for `auto`): (http://ideone.com/mxOCM1)

```
void print_reverse(std::string s)
{
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ) {
        auto it2 = std::find(it, s.end(), ' ');
        std::reverse(it, it2);
        it = it2;
        if (it != s.end()) {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a space when you reached the end of the original input line:

```
if printIt == scrambleWords.length()-1
    cout << " ";
```

Put this code in the inner for loop, after

```
if (isspace(scrambleWords[printIt]))
    break;
```

Note that breaking out of a for loop is not going to win you any programming beauty contests.